# Retrieve list of matched words in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-tuning

I'm new to PostgreSQL and really more than your more basic queries/inserts.

I've created a TSVector column to my table that I'm searching and have set the column to look at the specific column in the table.

Now what I'm trying to do is find out what words matched in a query.

If I had the query

```
SELECT ts_headline('the big red ball' , 'big & ball');
```

It would obviously return:

> "the **big** red **ball**"

Is there a way I can get it to return a list instead so I just see big and red in seperate rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the [regexp_split_to_table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) function?

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table(ts_headline('the big red ball'::text , 'big & ball'),' ');
 regexp_split_to_table 
-----------------------
 the
 <b>big</b>
 red
 <b>ball</b>
(4 rows)
```